# MS Access Query does not differentiate hiragana and katakana with standard equality operator

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, ms-access-2016, cjk

I recently ran into a problem with an MS Access query where I was searching a table containing Japanese text. Japanese has two alphabets, hiragana and katakana, with the same sound value, but different characters. For example, あ (hiragana) and ア (katakana) are both pronounced as 'a'. These two characters need to be treated as distinct for my `SELECT` query, but when I run the following query:

```
SELECT [KeywordID] FROM [Keyword] WHERE [Keyword].[Keyword]="あ"
```

It returns two values in my `Keyword` table, both あ and ア (incorrect behaviour for my purposes.)

I've figured out the workaround to ensure that these two characters are treated distinctly in `SELECT` queries, and wanted to post this here for future reference in case anyone else is working with Japanese characters in MS Access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I've found is to use `StrComp` in the `WHERE` clause to do a binary comparison. This will correctly differentiate hiragana and katakana, as in:

```
SELECT [KeywordID], [Keyword] FROM [Keyword] WHERE StrComp([Keyword].[Keyword], "あ", 0)=0
```

This returns one record, which is what I need.